# Why does rvm install ruby not work?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

It is said on [the Rails 3.2.9 blog](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/11/12/ann-rails-3-2-9-has-been-released/) that Ruby 1.9.3-p327 is recommended to be installed.  But

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p327
```

actually gives an error, and the log says:

> There is no checksum for
>   `'http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p327.tar.bz2'` or
>   `'ruby-1.9.3-p327.tar.bz2'`, it's not possible to validate it. If you
>   wish to continue with unverified download add `'--verify-downloads 1'`
>   after the command.

But I checked http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ and the `ruby-1.9.3-p286` has the same files as the `p327`.  So where is the checksum located?  Is it inside of the `.bz2` file?  So how should we install p327, is it just by

```
rvm install 1.9.3-p327 --verify-downloads 1
```

and is there security concerns, or are there other methods to install it safely?

Comment: Checkout this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735110/error-install-rvm-1-9-3][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735110/error-install-rvm-1-9-3

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First thing, make sure that your `rvm` version knows about this version by running `rvm list known`

On my machine, when I ran it the first time I got the following output for `known MRI Rubies`:

```
$ rvm list known
# MRI Rubies
[ruby-]1.8.6[-p420]
[ruby-]1.8.7-p370
[ruby-]1.8.7[-p371]
[ruby-]1.9.1[-p431]
[ruby-]1.9.2-p180
[ruby-]1.9.2-p290
[ruby-]1.9.2-p318
[ruby-]1.9.2[-p320]
[ruby-]1.9.2-head
[ruby-]1.9.3-preview1
[ruby-]1.9.3-rc1
[ruby-]1.9.3-p0
[ruby-]1.9.3-p125
[ruby-]1.9.3-p194
[ruby-]1.9.3-[p286]
[ruby-]1.9.3-head
ruby-head
```

So my version of `rvm` only knew about `1.9.3-[p286]` as the most recent version 1.9.3 version.

I got the latest version of `rvm` with the following command:

```
$ rvm get stable
```

After that, the list of `known MRI rubies` was as follows:

```
$ rvm list known
# MRI Rubies
[ruby-]1.8.6[-p420]
[ruby-]1.8.7-p370
[ruby-]1.8.7[-p371]
[ruby-]1.9.1[-p431]
[ruby-]1.9.2-p180
[ruby-]1.9.2-p290
[ruby-]1.9.2-p318
[ruby-]1.9.2[-p320]
[ruby-]1.9.2-head
[ruby-]1.9.3-preview1
[ruby-]1.9.3-rc1
[ruby-]1.9.3-p0
[ruby-]1.9.3-p125
[ruby-]1.9.3-p194
[ruby-]1.9.3-p286
[ruby-]1.9.3-[p327]
[ruby-]1.9.3-head
[ruby-]2.0.0-preview1
ruby-head
```

[A related thread on the rvm googlegroups discussion forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rubyversionmanager/aT2OdZFrblQ)

Comment: so in other words, to install the newest Ruby, we almost always need to run `rvm get stable` first... (provided that `rvm` is already updated to know about the latest Ruby patch level first)

Comment: Then afterwards, you can run ```rvm install 1.9.3-p327``` again.

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu 12.04, I use the cmd as follows, the newest version "-p327" will automatically detected and installed:

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```

The guide [Installing Rails on Ubuntu 12.04 with RVM support](http://mattslay.com/installing-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-with-rvm-support/) may helps: