# Error install rvm 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, rvm

Trying to solve this error....

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p392.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing requirements for smf, might require sudo password.
Installing required packages: libksba,
sqlite...................................................
Error running 'requirements_smf_libs_install libksba sqlite',
please read /Users/jm/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p392/package_install_libksba_sqlite.log
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.
You can get help using IRC: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm
```

Log file https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d9b590dfc121aab46579

Comment: Thanks Michael, and thank you for your great tutorials!

Answer (score 3):

That's  a bug for SM Framework implementation in autolibs, you need to open a ticket for RVM to fix it: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

You can overcome the problem by switching to homebrew:

```
rvm autolibs osx_brew
```

Comment: If you are using macports, it's `rvm autolibs macports`. thanks @mpapis!

Comment: Thank you, I decided to implode rvm and use rbenv.